# ANTLR - OutOfMemoryError expression-like grammar

Tags: out-of-memory, antlr

I'm using ANTLRT to parse expressions. When I add following rule, ANTLR runs out of memory (pls see log snippet at the end).

```
comp_expr returns [ AbstractLogicalExpression expr ]:
                expr1=or_type_expr LOG_LT expr2=or_type_expr { $expr = BinaryLogExpr.create( BinaryLogExpr.OP_TYPE.LT,
                                                                                       $expr1.expr, $expr2.expr ); } |
                expr1=or_type_expr LOG_GT expr2=or_type_expr { $expr = BinaryLogExpr.create( BinaryLogExpr.OP_TYPE.GT,
                                                                                       $expr1.expr, $expr2.expr ); } |
                or_type_expr { $expr = $or_type_expr.expr; };
```

Similar rules around (e.g. or_type_expr) in the same grammar work just fine. LOG_LT and LOG_GT are currently defined as following:

```
LOG_GT:         '>>';
LOG_LT:         '<<';
```

However, I tried other char sequences (like '.LT.' and '.GT' accordingly) but the effect is the same.

The only way to put it back to work is to comment-out the entire alternates containing LOG_LT and LOG_GT.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ArrayPredictionContext.<init>(ArrayPredictionContext.java:48)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.merge(PredictionContext.java:195)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.mergeArrays(PredictionContext.java:418)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.merge(PredictionContext.java:197)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.mergeArrays(PredictionContext.java:418)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionContext.merge(PredictionContext.java:197)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNConfigSet.add(ATNConfigSet.java:178)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1551)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closureCheckingStopState(ParserATNSimulator.java:1535)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.closure_(ParserATNSimulator.java:1603)
```

ANTLR versions is 4.5.1, Java runtime.

Anyone run into this and solved it before please?

Comment: Can you post an SSCCE that demonstrates this error? Http://SSCCE.org

Comment: Hi @Bart, I'll try to extract some minimal grammar; yet as far as I tried, removing any neighbouring rule just makes the remaining grammar work. However when I double the heap size, the problem remains, which makes me think that the issue is not about the memory availability but about the grammar complexity.

Comment: I re-worked the grammar by converting explicit BNF to predicated clauses thus efficiently reducing the number of rules. The problem is gone now. Yet what caused the problem is still a mystery to me. When I tried to branch-off the initial version, I somehow was not able to re-produce the error. Also, thorough looking through the lexer grammar did not reveal any rule that could match the zero string.